# chaning css background property not working in IE

Tags: jquery, css

I have an html table:

```
<table id=mytable>
<tr>
<th>Configurations</th>
<th>Dual 1.8GHz</th>
<th>Dual 2GHz</th>
<th>Dual 2.5GHz</th>
</tr>
</table>
```

and then I wrote the following:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

$('#mytable tr').hover(
  function () {
    $(this).css("background","yellow");
  }, 
  function () { 
    $(this).css("background","");
  }

);

</script>
```

When I hover over the table row, it becomes yellow in Firefox, but in IE it becomes white! Any ideas?

Comment: for IE try **backgroundColor** instead of **background**

Comment: I tested your codes on IE9, it was yellow color.: http://jsfiddle.net/uCKmj/242/

Comment: It would be cleaner and more reliable to use CSS instead. `table tr:hover { background-color:yellow; }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<style>
.someClass{/*all the proertiese you wanna set*/}
</style>
$('#mytable tr').hover(
  function () {
    $(this).addClass('someClass');
  }, 
  function () { 
    $(this).removeClass('someClass')
  }

);
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
$(this).css("backgroundColor","yellow");
```

And

```
$(this).css("backgroundColor","");
```

or you can pass a css properties object

```
$(this).css({
  background-color: 'yellow',
  background-image: 'url("blablabla")'
});
```

Answer (score 0):

do:

```
$(this).css("backgroundColor","yellow");
//or
$(this).css("background-color","yellow");
```